# calling php function by url with no securtiy risk

Tags: php, function, security, call

hello am still learning php and trying to call php function by url link and i did found this code

```
if(function_exists($_GET['f'])) {
$_GET['f']();
}
```

but it's not safe for my function so i did something like that

```
if($_GET['f']=='mouner'){
function mouner(){
    $s = 'my name is mouner';
    return($s);
}
echo mouner();
}
```

is that safe code ? and if it's not what is the best way to call function by url with no security risk

Comment: You don't need to add `echo` to your statement when calling a `function` in php..!

Comment: Also you don't need to put your `function mouner() { }` inside your `if` function as you may know that way you are declaring the function as local which you may not be able to call to in somewhere else outside your this if function..!

Comment: What do you mean by security risk??

Comment: Also I am still in shock how would even that work as you are writting in your first code as : `if (function_exists($_GET['f']))` as `if (isset($_GET['f']))` I do know but not yours one..!

Comment: A more concrete example might be helpful... as it stands now you could just execute `echo 'my name is mouner';` inside your if and it would be *exactly* equivalent.

Comment: Also this might be good too : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the first option is extremely risky, which is why you need to validate user inputs (including GET parameters).

Your second option does exactly that.  The code is not perfect but does solve that serious vulnerability.

Answer (score 5):

As @JuliePelletier suggested, you need to check your user input before executing any functions associated to it. Another handy way might be something like this:

```
$funcs["foo"] = function()
{
    echo "In foo function";
};

$funcs["bar"] = function()
{
    echo "In bar function";
};

if (isset($funcs[$_GET["f"]]))
    $funcs[$_GET["f"]]();
```

Store the functions (either anonymous or just by their name) in an associative array of allowed functions and just execute those.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot

Comment: Haven't seen this done in a long time haha! Got my vote for alternative suggestion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Julie has the right answer, just offering up some code cleanup:

```
if($_GET['f'] == 'mouner'){
    $s = 'my name is mouner';
    echo $s;
}
```

If you expect the result to have a lot of variation, could make use of `switch()` like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['f'])){
  $s = "My name is ";
  switch($_GET['f']){
    case 'mouner':
      $s .= "Mouner";
      break;
  }
  echo $s;
}
```